# How to create an elasticsearch k/v json field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following json object:

```
{
    "AVAILED_NOT_LIVE": {
        "ExceptionType": "Avail'd - Not Live",
        "ExceptionReason": "Clear For Rent",
        "ExpectedValue": "Cleared for VOD (Yes)",
        "FoundValue": "Cleared for VOD (No)"
    },
    "LIVE_NOT_AVAILED": {
        "ExceptionType": "Live - Not Avail'd",
        "ExceptionReason": "--",
        "ExpectedValue": "No",
        "FoundValue": "Yes"
    }
}
```

How would I create an index for this field? So far I have:

```
"properties": {
    "ExceptionType": { "type": "text" },
    "ExceptionReason": { "type": "text" },
    "ExpectedValue": { "type": "text" },
    "FoundValue": { "type": "text" },

 },
```

But this is missing the key (AVAILED_NOT_LIVE, LIVE_NOT_AVAILED), that may have various values. How would I dot hat mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I'd just insert a document and then customize the generated dynamic mapping:

Your 2 initial requests:

```
PUT /foo/_doc/1
{
  "AVAILED_NOT_LIVE": {
    "ExceptionType": "Avail'd - Not Live",
    "ExceptionReason": "Clear For Rent",
    "ExpectedValue": "Cleared for VOD (Yes)",
    "FoundValue": "Cleared for VOD (No)"
  },
  "LIVE_NOT_AVAILED": {
    "ExceptionType": "Live - Not Avail'd",
    "ExceptionReason": "--",
    "ExpectedValue": "No",
    "FoundValue": "Yes"
  }
}

GET /foo/_mapping
```

Response for the mapping, which you could then customize:

```
{
  "foo" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "_doc" : {
        "properties" : {
          "AVAILED_NOT_LIVE" : {
            "properties" : {
              "ExceptionReason" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "ExceptionType" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "ExpectedValue" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "FoundValue" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "LIVE_NOT_AVAILED" : {
            "properties" : {
              "ExceptionReason" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "ExceptionType" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "ExpectedValue" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "FoundValue" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

PS: From the mapping it's also getting clear how nested objects are being mapped — by having properties in a property.

Comment: right, but the point here is I may have more than two 'keys' -- not just `AVAILED_NOT_LIVE` and `LIVE_NOT_AVAILED` and I don't want to have to change my index every time I add a new key. Is that possible to do?

Comment: Not with that structure. Maybe you could do something like `{ "events": [ { "type": "AVAILED_NOT_LIVE", "ExceptionType": "...", ...}, { "type": "LIVE_NOT_AVAILED", "ExceptionType": "..." }, ... ] }`

Comment: got it. In that case would you suggest just doing an array of objects, and putting the `Key` into its own field called "ExceptionCode" ?

Comment: Yes, that sounds generally good. BUT be sure to understand the implications and check out the nested data type in the docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html. This might be surprising at first.